# Cannot assign a string to an array

Tags: c

I need to create a structure whose member is an character array like below:

```
struct Person{
    char name [100];

};
```

Why the below results in a incompatible types error? And how to fix it?

```
struct Person john;
john.name = "John";
```

what is the difference between the assignment above and bellow, which works well:

```
char str[100] = "this is a string";
```

Comment: The "assignment below" is *not* an assignment.

Comment: You cannot assign to an array, use `strcpy`.

Comment: It may help if you think that C has no strings. It does have string literals, which can be used in a few different ways, and it has standard library functions for manipulating byte sequences where 0-byte marks the end, AKA "strings". But if you are used to strings of almost any other language, these are not something you would call "strings".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`john.name = "John";` is an assignment (which is not possible in this case) while

```
char str[100] = "this is a string";
```

is definition with initialization.

`john.name = "John";` is an invalid statement in C because an array can't be a left operand of `=` operator. You need `strcpy` or `strncpy` to copy a string.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't allow you to use the assignment operator with arrays. There is a special provision that allows you to initialize arrays with string literals:

```
struct Person john = {"John"};
```